# Pipelined processes status monitoring in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring

Assume I have a bunch of pipelined processes launched in a form like: `a | b | c | ... | z`. The processes are started with some script that accepts a couple of command-line arguments and builds the 'pipeline' of processes. This bunch of processes may be thought of as a single pipeline.
Also, there is a script that allows one to see status of the pipeline and detect somehow whether it is working or not.
I know there are a lot of tools like `supervisor` or `circus` (see [here](http://blog.crocodoc.com/post/48703468992/process-managers-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly)). I'd like to use `mmonit` but it is proprietary and I'm looking for some free software that will be like pinging the pipeline with provided script and do some custom actions.

Of course there is nothing better suiting my conditions than my own software but I'd like to see if there is already smth suitable.

Any suggestions?